# How to Schedule a Vertex AI Notebook Execution with Custom Environment Including Scripts and Config Files?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, scheduling, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm working with Google Cloud's Vertex AI Workbench and have developed a Jupyter notebook that relies on a specific project structure, including several folders, Python scripts, and a configuration file. When I run the notebook manually within the Workbench, everything works as expected because the environment contains all these necessary files and dependencies.

I want to automate the execution of this notebook on a schedule, ensuring that the execution environment replicates the manual run environment, with access to the same folders, scripts, and config file.

Could you guide me on how to schedule the notebook's execution in Vertex AI Workbench so that the scheduled run utilizes an environment that mirrors this setup? Specifically, I need a simple approach that ensures the scheduled execution has access to the same project directory structure, including all necessary files and dependencies, just as when run manually.

Comment: Do you want to schedule it to perform production transformation?

Comment: I'm not sure what is it production transformation, but the notebook loads and processes data from Big Query tables and Google Cloud Storage, trains a Catboost classifier, and uploads the results to Big Query tables. I hope my answer is relevant to your question.

Comment: yes, but my true remark is: a notebook is a developer tool. When you have finished your experiment, package the code in a container and run it any where (VertexAI custom training, Cloud Run Jobs, Batch, even Cloud Build or Dataproc if you wish!!). But do not try to automate a dev environment!

Comment: What the simplest way to package the code I described in a container?